# Change cell range when cell value is changed to 'value'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to change the cell range Worksheet!L2:L20 to blank when Newsletter!K6 changes to 'FINISHED'

```
function onEdit(e) {
      var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Newsletter");
      var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Worksheet");
      var cell = sheet1.getRange(6,11).getValues();
      var cells = sheet2.getRange(2,12,20);
      var finished = "FINISHED";

      if (cell === "FINISHED") {

      cells.setValue("");

      } else {

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrow down the onEdit to the sheet and cell to monitor then do this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var editedCell = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  if(sheet=="Newsletter"){
  if(e.value=="FINISHED"){
     ss.getRange("Worksheet!L2:L20").clearContent() 
  }}}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "onEdit(FINISHED)". This is the error I get when trying to run the script

Comment: It works fine for me. Here is my test spreadsheet. Make a copy and try it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W6MVev-Z3tI6ZAawaTYdts_XQ79TqAN0IYrb2xhUbug/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Copied it and it works, thanks a lot!
Still no clue as to why it didn't work the first time.